# default value of \tabcolsep

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  A11 & A12\\
  A21 & A22
\end{tabular}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  B11 & B12\\
  B21 & B22
\end{tabular}

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{??}                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  C11 & C12\\
  C21 & C22
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I would like the column separation `\tabcolsep` in C table to be the same as in the A table. What value should I provide in line `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{??}`

Comment: Use `\showthe\tabcolsep`  (or `\the\tabcolsep` if you want to print it) then latex will tell you the value.

Comment: You can also store the value of `\tabcolsep` in some other macro before setting it to zero and later restore it.

Comment: normally a tabular is in a group (from table or center or some other environment so tabcolsep woul just reset itself at the end of the group anyway, not often you need a global change and a global reset

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Usually a `tabular` is in a surrounding environment such as `table` or `center` so the `\tabcolsep` setting is local.  Or, as shown below, you can add an extra `{}` group to arrange that.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  A11 & A12\\
  A21 & A22
\end{tabular}

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  B11 & B12\\
  B21 & B22
\end{tabular}}

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{??}                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  C11 & C12\\
  C21 & C22
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ulrike Fischer pointed out in the comments, you can assess the dimension of `\tabcolsep` easily with `\the\tabcolsep` or `\showthe\tabcolsep`. You will find out that it is 6.0pt by default.

If you would like to change it for just one `tabular` environment, I would suggest that you store the value of `\tabcolsep` in some other macro before setting it to zero. Then, you will be able to restore it later without the need to know the actual value at all.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  A11 & A12\\
  A21 & A22
\end{tabular}

\newlength{\oldtabcolsep}
\setlength{\oldtabcolsep}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  B11 & B12\\
  B21 & B22
\end{tabular}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\oldtabcolsep}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  C11 & C12\\
  C21 & C22
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Another way to suppress the gap between columns would be to place the `@{}` parameter between the column definitions:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{} c @{}}
  B11 & B12\\
  B21 & B22
\end{tabular}
```